# How do i insert a macro when a new sheet is created

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to insert a macro when a new sheet is created. For example, i have a main worksheet which has all the data, and when i click on a command button, it filters out the rows and columns i need and paste it on a new worksheet called Europe. Is it possible to have a command button ready set there when the "Europe" worksheet is created?

Comment: Yes. What's your question ?

Comment: So how do i do it? Currently i have the codes to run the function that i need. What i need now is help with getting a commandbutton there when the new worksheet(in this case Europe) created.

Comment: So you want a commandbutton, bound to a macro, inserted into the new sheet?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is something hanging off the `Workbook.VBProject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following macro will create a new sheet, set it's name, create a new button on the sheet, change the label and assign an existing macro to the button.

```
Sub AddWorksheetWithMacroButton()
    Dim btn As Button
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    'Create new worksheet
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))

    'Set worksheet Name
    wks.Name = "MyNewSheet"

    'Add new button to worksheet (left pos, top pos, width, height)
    Set btn = wks.Buttons.Add(390, 61.5, 94.5, 31.5)

    'Lable button
    btn.Characters.Text = "Button Label"

    'Assign existing macro (Macro1) to button
    btn.OnAction = "Macro1"
End Sub
```

Comment: so for "Macro1", i change it to this? btn.OnAction = ArrangeColumn ? Sorry i just started to learn vba, I need alot of assistance.

Comment: Assuming that you already have a macro like this `Sub ArrangeColumn ...` located in a separate module (not on a specific sheet) then yes, you can set the button to trigger this macro: `btn.OnAction = "ArrangeColumn"`.